# Prove from the definition that the function $f(x) = |x − 4|$ is differentiable at all $x \ne 4$, but is not differentiable at $x = 4$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove from the definition that the function $f(x) = |x − 4|$ is differentiable at all $x \ne 4$, but is not differentiable at $x = 4$.

The second part is straight forward as I just demonstrate with the definition of the derivative that the left and right side limits do not coincide, implying the limit does not exist, implying f is not differentiable at $x=4$.

I am having a hard time rigorously proving the first part. Clearly I can demonstrate that if we choose a point on both sides of 4 that the limit does exist for all points in $R$ $st$ $ x_1\gt4$, $x_2\lt4$. Is this enough for a second semester undergrad analysis course?

How would I go about it in a more rigorous fashion using the definition of the derivative and definition of limits if need be?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is enough.

Comment: You can also argue, $x\mapsto x-4$ for $x>4$ and $x\mapsto -(x-4)$ for $x<4$ are differentiable and conclude $x\mapsto |x-4|$ is differentiable, as long as $x\neq 4$.

Comment: You can relate to theorem about left and right differentiate of a function: $F(x)$ is differentiable if and only if left differentiate and right differentiate both exist and equal.